# How can I get the documents having an id that are attribute values of another document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

This is an exemple:

```
{"_id": 1,
"attr1": "x",
"class":"vehicle"}
{"_id": 2,
"attr1": "xf",
"class":"vehicle"}
{"_id": 3,
"attr1": "xz",
"class":"vehicle"}
{"_id": 4,
"attr1": "xddz",
"class":"vehicle"}

{"_id": 11,
"attr1": "xy",
"class":"seat",
"vehicle":[1,2]}

{"_id": 12,
"attr1": "exy",
"class":"seat",
"vehicle":[3,2]}
```

I would like to know what query or aggregate to use in order to get the document with "class" vehicle having their ids in the array of attribute value of the documents with class "seat".

In our example I need to have those documents returned:

```
{"_id": 1,
"attr1": "x",
"class":"vehicle"}
{"_id": 2,
"attr1": "xf",
"class":"vehicle"}
{"_id": 3,
"attr1": "xz",
"class":"vehicle"}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   What did you try so far and what did not work?   Also: that data design is a little suspect...

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti
Thank you!
I am still a beginner in mongodb and I am trying a lookup that is not working.
For the data design I just gave an example that is so simple

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I need an idea how to do that cause I am blocked. I just need the trigger idea to continue

Comment: @developer_jun $lookup that you mentioned seems a sensible way to start with. What have you tried? What was the *not working* exception?

Comment: @developer_jun  Remember:  At stackoverflow, the protocol is to show your work and explain what is not working as you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming every document is in the same collection, you could do something like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "root": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      res: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$root",
          "as": "values",
          "cond": {
            $in: [
              "$$values._id",
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  input: "$root.vehicle",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {
                    "$setUnion": [
                      "$$value",
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  },
                  
                }
              },
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$res"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$res"
    }
  }
])
```

You can check on https://mongoplayground.net/p/iYG8o0ZOde5

Comment: Beware of that first `$group`.   It will turn a collection of 1m documents into an array of 1m items.   If you only have 100 docs or so then you're probably OK.